# Yii generate model without Gii

Tags: php, yii, model, frameworks, gii

I need to generate a model file without the use of Gii. Are there any command Yii?

```
$table = "myTable";
Yii::app()->generateModel($table); // ?
```

Comment: What Yii version are you using? Yii 1.x?

Comment: Yii Framework 1.1.17

Comment: Please see my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps is officially deprecated, you can generate code with [Yii Command Line Tools](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app-yiic)

I have tested it with Yii 1.1.17.

First you need to create a new file on `protected/commands` called for example `NewmodelCommand.php` [to create a new yii command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console). We need to avoid to use shell interactive tool and call command directly from our code in controllers, models, etc. To get it, we inherit Yii core class [`ModelCommand`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/04f97932ddfbf9c5bdaae0a6a41b851544704a27/framework/cli/commands/shell/ModelCommand.php). This class originally force person to type on interactive shell.

```
<?php

Yii::import('system.cli.commands.shell.ModelCommand');


class NewmodelCommand extends ModelCommand
{

}
```

That is all. You can test command from CLI into your operating system. In Linux, open your terminal and go to `/protected/` directory and type:

```
./yiic
```

You will see something like this:

```
...
The following commands are available:
 - message
 - migrate
 - newmodel
 - shell
 - webapp
...
```

Play a little with it. Type again:

```
./yiic newmodel
```

And you will see all command help and documentation.

To generate a model with this command you need at least `model_name` as first parameter. Command will use same model name as database table name:

```
./yiic newmodel MyNewModel
```

If you have different model and database name:

```
./yiic newmodel MyNewModel tbl_new_model
```

If you have troubles using yiic, locating/connecting your db, etc, make sure to setup properly your console environment on [protected/config/console.php](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#customizing-console-applications) and [check all official docs about Yii console applications](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console).

Finally in your code you can use your command as you want:

```
$path = '/full/path/to/protected';
$new_model_name = 'MyNewModel';
shell_exec( $path . "/./yiic newmodel $new_model_name" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is a command. You could create the model, or the command, yourself. Other option would be to make the requests to Gii via curl.